# Как записать данные в локальный текстовый файл с помощью Angular2?

Tags: angular2

Создаю простое приложение на angular2. Нужно записать данные в\прочитать данные из текстового файла на моём компьютере, приложение слишком маленькое и простое, чтобы использовать базу данных и API. Есть ли способ так сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы считать данные из файла можно использовать [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Чтобы выгрузить данные в файл:

```
if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
    let blobData = new Blob([data], {type: this.fileType + ";charset=utf-8;"});
    navigator.msSaveBlob(blobData, this.fileName );
}else {
    jQuery(this._el).append("<a></a>");
    jQuery("a", this._el)
        .attr("href", "data:" + this.fileType + ";base64," + btoa(data))
        .attr("download", this.fileName);
    jQuery("a", this._el)[0].click();

    jQuery("a", this._el).remove();
}
```

В примере используется jQuery, вам можно попробовать и без него.

А вообще попробуйте использовать [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)